# GCE VM not connecting from Terminal but working in Web SSH

Tags: google-cloud

Until before couple of days in Mac Terminal I was able to connect to GCE VM without trouble. Now when I tried any VM it is not connecting. Same VMs are connecting from WEB SSH ok. Does it need to be fixed on Mac or VM side? As none of VM is connecting I felt the issue must be in Mac side. Log didn't display much info, is there anything can be done?

```
gcloud compute --project "<projectname>" ssh --zone "us-central1-b" "instance-dm-f07a" --ssh-flag="-vvvvv"

OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 104.197.95.27 [104.197.95.27] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 104.197.95.27 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 104.197.95.27 port 22: Operation timed out
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your instance is closed by firewall from your current address. Seems that you open access to your ip or network when you create your instance and after some time your external ip address have changed.

You could check your current external ip using command `curl wtfismyip.com/text` and after that check your GCloud VPC firewall (and also firewall on your instance if you have any like `iptables`) to see are there any restrictions for ssh (port 22) and your current ip address.

Comment: have tried and it is not the case. without changing configuration in cloud, sometimes it is connecting from terminal and sometimes it not connecting.